# Running python in excel using xlwings, trouble reading 'LOG_FILE'

Tags: python, excel, vba

I just installed `xlwings` for mac and I'm trying to execute Python code from within an existing Excel document.  The document is saved in my folder, call it

```
\Users\me\my_dir\my_file.xlsm
```

I've made a copy of `xlwings.bas` in `\my_dir` (perhaps unnecessarily) and have imported it into `my_file.xlsm`.

I have a module `my_module.py` with a function `my_sub()` that goes to the internet, pulls some data, and wants to put this data into a cell in the Excel spreadsheet (I should add that an earlier version of `my_sub()` that just printed the data to the terminal worked fine).

Anyways, when I try to run this using RunPython, I get a "path/file access error" on the line

```
Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
```

and in the locals window, `FileName` is the name of the `LOG_FILE`

```
"Macintosh HD:Users:Me:my_dir:xlwings_log.txt"
```

it's giving me a file_path error.

I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the `xlwings` code, since when I ran a much simpler python script using `RunPython`, it worked just fine.  But I have no clue how to debug this since the error is tucked away in the source code.

Has anybody else seen this error or know how to get around it?

Comment: What version of xlwings are you using? Check at the top of the xlwings module in VBA. Also, when the code breaks - is there an `xlwings_log.txt`file existing in the indicated directory?

Comment: Figured it out; I was running putting a bad command string into RunPython and so Excel stayed on 'running' instead of 'Ready'.  When I tried to run the macro again, it got screwed up (presumably because the LOG_FILE was already open or something like that). Anyway, it's now fixed.